# wordpress header file will not connect to my index file

Tags: wordpress-theming

I am attempting to create an wordpress theme from scratch but not able get the header or footer files to show.I'm not sure were to go from here any help would be appreciated

Here is the code on my index.php file

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

 <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-8 blog-main">
        <blockquote>
        <p>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Sed              posuere consectetur est at lobortis.</p>
      </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

      <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">Another blog post</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">December 23, 2013 by <a    `enter code here`href="#">Jacob</a></p>

        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis <a href="#">dis parturient montes</a>, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Sed posuere consectetur est at lobortis. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.</p>
        <blockquote>
          <p>Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. <strong>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis</strong> ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
        </blockquote>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        <p>Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros.</p>
      </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

      <div class="blog-post">
        <h2 class="blog-post-title">New feature</h2>
        <p class="blog-post-meta">December 14, 2013 by <a `enter code here`href="#">Chris</a></p>

        <p>Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
        <ul>
          <li>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</li>
          <li>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus.</li>
          <li>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
        <p>Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue.</p>
      </div><!-- /.blog-post -->

      <nav>
        <ul class="pager">
          <li><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>

    </div><!-- /.blog-main -->

    <div class="col-sm-3 col-sm-offset-1 blog-sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-module sidebar-module-inset">
        <h4>About</h4>
        <p>Etiam porta <em>sem malesuada magna</em> mollis euismod. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Archives</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">March 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">February 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">January 2014</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">December 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">November 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">October 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">September 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">August 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">July 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">June 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">May 2013</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">April 2013</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-module">
        <h4>Elsewhere</h4>
        <ol class="list-unstyled">
          <li><a href="#">GitHub</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ol>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.blog-sidebar -->

  </div><!-- /.row -->

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

And here is my header file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
 <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other    head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description') ?>">
<meta name="author" content="<?php bloginfo ('author') ?>">

<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> | <?php is_front_page() ?      `enter code here`bloginfo('description') : wp_title(); ?><?php wp_title(); ?></title> 

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/bootstrap.css"   rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

<?php wp_head(); ?>
```

```
<div class="blog-masthead">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="blog-nav">
      <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New features</a>
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">Press</a>
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">New hires</a>
      <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">About</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
  <div class="blog-header">
    <h1 class="blog-title"><?php bkoginfo('name'); ?></h1>
    <p class="lead blog-description"><?php bloginfo('description')  ?></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your header or footer code must be include in your wordpress header.php or footer.php
or you have a template for header then use get_template_part ('your/directory').
Follow this link https://codex.wordpress.org/Designing_Headers 
it might be helpful for you

Comment: Thank you this fixed it. And the link helps alot thanks again.